# Python: Trouble with Dictionaries, cTurtle, and a little Recursion

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm supposed to do the following

> Change the applyProduction function so that the dictionary of rules
>   maps each symbol not to a single replacement string, but to a list of
>   alternative strings, one of which is randomly chosen each time a
>   replacement needs to be performed. (You can randomly choose an element
>   of a list using the choice function within the random module.) As in
>   the original version of applyProduction, some symbols may not be
>   listed in the rules at all, in which case they should be left
>   unchanged.

The applyProduction function looks like

```
def applyProduction(axiom,rules,n):
    for i in range(n):
        newString = ""
        for ch in axiom:
            newString = newString + rules.get(ch,ch)
        axiom = newString
    return axiom
```

And the one that I've done is

```
def applyProduction(axiom,rules,n):
    for i in range(n):
        newString = ""
        for ch in axiom:
            listOfRules = rules.get(ch)
            doIt = random.choice(listOfRules)
            newString = newString + doIt
        axiom = newString
    return axiom
```

So I'm trying to get all of the values of the dictionary associated with the letter ch.  And then choose a random on of them.  I think what I'm trying to do is the way to do it and that it should work, but when I do it I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    lsystem('F-F-F',{'F':'F-F-F-GG', 'F':'F+G++F', 'G':'GG'}, 3,(-100,-100),0,120,25)
  File "C:\Python33\lsystems.py", line 61, in lsystem
    instructions = applyProduction(axiom,rules,depth)
  File "C:\Python33\lsystems.py", line 16, in applyProduction
    doIt = random.choice(listOfRules)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\random.py", line 249, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

And i don't really know what that means.  Any help is appreciated.

Other functions involved.

```
def drawLS(aTurtle,instructions,angle,distance):
    stateSaver = []
    for cmd in instructions:
        if cmd == 'F':
            aTurtle.forward(distance)
        elif cmd == 'G':
            aTurtle.up()
            aTurtle.forward(distance)
            aTurtle.down()
        elif cmd == 'B':
            aTurtle.backward(distance)
        elif cmd == '+':
            aTurtle.right(angle)
        elif cmd == '-':
            aTurtle.left(angle)
        elif cmd == '[':
            pos = aTurtle.position()
            head = aTurtle.heading()
            stateSaver.append((pos,head))
        elif cmd == ']':
            pos,head = stateSaver.pop()
            aTurtle.up() 
            aTurtle.setposition(pos)
            aTurtle.setheading(head)
            aTurtle.down()
```

.

```
def lsystem(axiom,rules,depth,initialPosition,heading,angle,length):
    aTurtle = Turtle()
    aTurtle.speed(0)       # this line improves on Listing 9.8
    aTurtle.shape('blank') # this line improves on Listing 9.8
    aTurtle.up()
    aTurtle.setposition(initialPosition)
    aTurtle.down()
    aTurtle.setheading(heading)
    ## The variable "instructions" was called "newRules" in Listing 9.8,
    ## which was misleading regarding what kind of thing it names.
    instructions = applyProduction(axiom,rules,depth)
    drawLS(aTurtle,instructions,angle,length)
    aTurtle.exitOnClick()
```

Comment: `listOfRules = rules.get(ch)`: ch is not in the `rules` dictionary, so the `get` method is returning `None`, you then pass this `None` to `random.choice` and it's not happy about it.

Comment: You cannot have **two** `F` keys in a dictionary; keys are always unique.

Comment: Also, you have no `-` in your `rules` but do have the `-` character in `axiom`.

Comment: Okay, I'm still not sure I fully get it but I'm at least slightly less lost.  thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
>
> And i don't really know what that means. Any help is appreciated.

In line 16, the `random.choice(listOfRules)` is failing because *listOfRule* is *None* rather than a list.

In line 15, the `listOfRules = rules.get(ch)` is returning *None* because it isn't finding an entry for *ch*.

Comment: Yes but I tried to run

    lsystem('FFF',{'F':'F-F-F-GG', 'F':'F+G++F', 'G':'GG'}, 3,    (-100,-100),0,120,25)

And I got the same error.  So F should have two entries shouldn't it?

Also my lsystem function and drawLS function are going to be edited into the Original if they're needed

Comment: @Jonerhan: you cannot have **two** `F` keys.

Comment: Isn't that what the question is asking?  I'm sorry I'm just really lost